# Setting Retrofit RestAdapter.LogLevel to anything other than FULL results in Empty Response Body

Tags: android, json, rest, gson, retrofit

I have the following 3 classes and 1 interface in my project.  Setting logging to NONE results in a "success", but with an empty response body (seen in getMovies()->success() below).  The URL that is output in that error can be cut & pasted into a browser and it works perfectly.  If I change logging to FULL everything works perfectly, however, my API key is then plainly visible in the LogCat output.

```
public class RestClient {

    private ApiService apiService;

    public RestClient(String endpoint, boolean enableLogging) {

        Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
                .registerTypeAdapterFactory(new ItemTypeAdapterFactory())
                .setDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd")
                .setPrettyPrinting()
                .excludeFieldsWithoutExposeAnnotation()
                .create();

        RestAdapter restAdapter = new RestAdapter.Builder()
                .setLogLevel(BuildConfig.DEBUG && enableLogging ? RestAdapter.LogLevel.FULL : RestAdapter.LogLevel.NONE)
                .setEndpoint(endpoint)
                .setConverter(new GsonConverter(gson))
                .setRequestInterceptor(new SessionRequestInterceptor())
                .build();

        apiService = restAdapter.create(ApiService.class);
    }

    public ApiService getApiService() {
        return apiService;
    }

}


public class ServiceEventHandler {

    private boolean isRetrofitLoggingEnabled;
    private String rottenTomatoesUrl;
    private String rottenTomatoesApiKey;

    public ServiceEventHandler(Context context) {
        isRetrofitLoggingEnabled = Boolean.valueOf(context.getString(R.string.retrofit_logging_enabled));
        rottenTomatoesUrl = context.getString(R.string.movies_url);
        rottenTomatoesApiKey = context.getString(R.string.rotten_tomatoes_api_key); /* Look in res/values/secret.xml */
        if (rottenTomatoesApiKey.equals("REPLACE WITH YOUR KEY")) {
            Toast.makeText(context, context.getString(R.string.error_replace_api_key), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }

    /**
     * 'IN THEATER' MOVIES
     */
    @Subscribe
    public void getMovies(final GetMoviesEvent event) {
        /**
         * rotten_tomatoes_api_key is stored in a strings resource file named secret.xml and
         * located in res/values, but secret.xml has been added to .gitignore so my key doesn't
         * end up in source control.
         *
         * simply create your own res/values/secret.xml file with your own Rotten Tomatoes API
         * key and the app will run as expected.
         */
        ApiService apiService = new RestClient(rottenTomatoesUrl, isRetrofitLoggingEnabled).getApiService();
        apiService.getMovies(rottenTomatoesApiKey, event.getPageNumber(), event.getPageLimit(), new RestCallback<Movies>(event.getCallNumber()) {
            @Override
            public void success(Movies movies, Response response) {
                if (response.getBody().length() > 0) {
                    EventBus.post(movies);
                } else {
                    EventBus.post(new APIErrorEvent(RetrofitError.unexpectedError(response.getUrl(), new HttpException("Empty Body")), event.getCallNumber()));
                }
            }
        });
    }
}


public abstract class RestCallback<T> implements Callback<T> {

    private int callNumber;

    public RestCallback(int callNumber) {
        this.callNumber = callNumber;
    }

    @Override
    public void failure(RetrofitError error) {
        EventBus.post(new APIErrorEvent(error, this.callNumber));
    }

    public int getCallNumber() {
        return callNumber;
    }
}


public interface ApiService {

    final static String APPSETTINGS = "/application_settings.json";
    final static String MOVIES = "/in_theaters.json";

    // IN THEATER MOVIES
    @GET(MOVIES)
    void getMovies(@Query("apikey") String key, @Query("page") int page, @Query("page_limit") int page_limit, Callback<Movies> cb);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`response.getBody()` will return a TypedInput and its length method (http://square.github.io/retrofit/javadoc/retrofit/mime/TypedInput.html#length--) makes no guarantee about returning a number greater than zero when a response body is present.  A value less than or equal to 0 doesn't mean you don't have a body, just that it can't tell you how long it is.

I'm *guessing* the reason this only shows up when logging is turned off is due to buffering details needed to support logging.

You'll probably want to do tests in `onSuccess` around something other than that length (ex: response status code or on the `Movies` object.

Comment: That's 4 hours of my life I can't get back, but a valuable lesson learned.  *sigh*